# MySQL: Counting number of instances of numerous objects with use of intersection

Tags: mysql

I am trying to list all of the guitar rigs that contain `chorusEffectPedal` and `delayEffectPedal`.

I have a `guitarRig` database. In this database, the `parts` (I.e. `amplifier`, `cabinet`, `microphone`, `guitarType`, `guitarStringType`, `patchCord`, `effectsPedal`, etc.) comprise a guitar rig. a Guitar rig can have many parts, and parts can belong to many guitar rigs.

Here are my tables:

```
Table GuitarRig:
    name
    numberofParts

Table Part:
    name
    guitarRig references GuitarRig(name)
    product references Product(name)

Table Product:
    name
    part references Part(name)
    barcodeNumber
```

---

So far what I have is this:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM(
        SELECT name
        FROM Part
        WHERE name = 'chorusEffectPedal') INTERSECT
    (SELECT recipeName
     FROM 
     WHERE name = 'delayEffectPedal');
```

I realize that INTERSECT is not a keyword statement anymore (i.e. there is no `INTERSECT` function that exists), however this is the algorithm I want to use.

I don't know if I'm off to the right foot, but to me this seems like a good start.

I should also note that although I realize there have been other questions posted before me regarding `INTERSECT`, I feel they do not apply to this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is Part.guitarRig the same as GuitarRig.name?

then it is simple:

```
select cep.guitarRig as guitarRig from 
(select guitarRig from Part where name='chorusEffectPedal') cep join 
(select guitarRig from Part where name='delayEffectPedal') dep
on cep.guitarRig=dep.guitarRig;
```

P.S. Regarding REFERENCES as part of the column spec, MySQL doesn't seem to use them:

> MySQL does not recognize or support “inline REFERENCES specifications”
>   (as defined in the SQL standard) where the references are defined as
>   part of the column specification. MySQL accepts REFERENCES clauses
>   only when specified as part of a separate FOREIGN KEY specification.

source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html

Comment: the `references` word that I used above in the column spec are not any code; they are just there for intuitive understanding so that my database is easily understood by those who took the time to read my post. Your solution worked flawlessly. Thanks!